# R-project data frame returning too many columns

Tags: r, function, dataframe

Working through an R tutorial that I'm having a hard time understanding.

Directory is a folder with numerous csv files. The function takes  as id either one of more of the files and returns the number of records in each.

My function:

```
complete <- function(directory,id = 1:332) {

   csvfiles <- sprintf("/Users/myname/Desktop/%s/%03d.csv", directory, id)

   nrows <- sapply( csvfiles, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)))
   data.frame(ID=sprintf('%03d', id), 
              countrows=sapply(csvfiles,function(x) length(count.fields(x))),
             row.names=id
           )
       }
```

Then complete("specdata", 100:105)
Returns

```
    ID countrows
100 100      1097
101 101       731
102 102      1462
103 103      3653
104 104      2558
105 105      2192
```

What must I do so that the left most column is a sequence starting 1? So that, for example, the first record would be 1 100 & 1092, the second record 2 101 & 731

Comment: Your data frame has only two columns.  Your first "column" is in fact just the row names. You can change this with `rownames(specdata) <- 1:5`

Comment: You are explicitly setting the rownames in your function too - remove this line: `row.names=id`

Comment: @thelatemail I did but then got the full directory like so:                                id nobs
/Users/myname/Desktop/specdata/100.csv 100 1097
/Users/myname/Desktop/specdata/101.csv 101  731
etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first apparent column is just the names of the rows (look at e.g. `ncol(specdata)`). You can rename rows as follows:

```
row.names(specdata) <- 1:nrow(specdata)
```

Comment: Michael thanks but that does not seem to work. How exactly should I integrate it?

Comment: @DougFirr Save the result of `complete` into a variable, say `specdata`, and run the line Michael suggested. By just typing `rownames(specdata)` (I usually use this function, not `row.names`), you should see all row names. By assigning something to it, you are effectivel changing it. If you assign `NULL`, you will remove row names.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the function use this inside the dataframe call:

```
row.names = 1: length(id)
```